# using regex for validation in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, email

```js
$("#signUp").click(function(e){

var email= $('#email').val()
if(email=='' || email != "/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/"){
  $('#emailErr').html('**Invalid email')
  e.preventDefault();
} else {
  $('#emailErr').hide();
}
```

**what is the mistake there? It prevents the submit button.**

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing `parenthesis` and a `curly bracket`.

Adding `});` should fix.

Answer (score 0):

You compare the content of input to the regular expression using `!=`. That is true for every string that is not literally equal to the regexp - it does NOT try to match the regular expression, it compares two strings of which one happens to be a regular expression.
The only way for the comparison to be false is it you enter the regular expression into the input.

To check if a string matches a regular expression, use

`if (email.match(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/))`

Note that regular expression literals do not have any quotes around them.